# Hide unmanaged network interfaces in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, network-manager, 16.04, vmware

On my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 I have VMware Workstation 12 Pro (legitimately) installed, so there are virtual network interfaces that are unmanaged by `network-manager` but they still show up in the menu in panel.

[image: Network Manager]

I have tried removing them via `[keyfile]` in the `NetworkManager.conf` file, to no avail.

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX;mac:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
```

So is there some alternative way to hide these interfaces from the network manager?

I did quite a bit of Googling to no avail so please excuse my ignorance if this is an already answered question.

Comment: See the corresponding bug report here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1458322

Answer (score 1):

There is a GNOME Shell extension that hides unmanaged network devices: [nm-hide-unmanaged](https://github.com/linniksa/nm-hide-unmanaged-gnome-shell-extension)

You have to install it manually according to the [instructions in the README](https://github.com/linniksa/nm-hide-unmanaged-gnome-shell-extension#nm-hide-unmanaged) (it doesn't appear to be available from the [GNOME extensions directory](https://extensions.gnome.org/)).